# Using RegEx split the string

Tags: regex

I have a string like '[1]-[2]-[3],[4]-[5],[6,7,8],[9]' or '[Computers]-[Apple]-[Laptop],[Cables]-[Cables,Connectors],[Adapters]', I'd like the Pattern to get the list result, but don't know how to figure out the pattern. Basically the comma is the split, but [6,7,8] itself contains the comma as well.

```
the string: [1]-[2]-[3],[4]-[5],[6,7,8],[9]
the result:
[1]-[2]-[3]
[4]-[5]
[6,7,8]
[9]

or

the string: [Computers]-[Apple]-[Laptop],[Cables]-[Cables,Connectors],[Adapters]
the result:
[Computers]-[Apple]-[Laptop]
[Cables]-[Cables,Connectors]
[Adapters]
```

Comment: Can you give a sample output for this code?

Comment: Oh, I see. This isn't really regex, you can use a simple split.

Comment: the splitter should work, but i want to use the Pattern, like RegEx.match

Comment: The question is unclear. "[1]" is a regex.  Or do you mean that [1] stands in for the first list item? Or is 1 the list items, and the brackets and the dashes are literals?

Comment: Hi Joshua, the last part is the result i should get from the Pattern. and all the brackets and dashes are literals

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I believe the best approach here is to use split (as presented by @j__m's answer), here's an approach that uses matching rather than splitting.

Regex:

```
(\[.*?\](?!-))
```

Example usage:

```
String input = "[Computers]-[Apple]-[Laptop],[Cables]-[Cables,Connectors],[Adapters]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\[.*?\\](?!-))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```

Resulting output:

```
[Computers]-[Apple]-[Laptop]
[Cables]-[Cables,Connectors]
[Adapters]
```

Comment: thanks for that. it is exactly what i want. you are champion : )

Answer (score 3):

```
,(?=\[)
```

This pattern splits on any comma that is followed by a bracket, but keeps the bracket within the result text.

The `(?=*stuff*)` is known as a "lookahead assertion".  It acts as a condition for the match but is not itself part of the match.

In C# code:

```
String inputstring = "[Computers]-[Apple]-[Laptop],[Cables]-[Cables,Connectors],[Adapters]";
foreach(String s in Regex.Split(inputstring, @",(?=\[)"))
    System.Console.Out.WriteLine(s);
```

In Java code:

```
String inputstring = "[Computers]-[Apple]-[Laptop],[Cables]-[Cables,Connectors],[Adapters]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(",(?=\\[)"));
for(String s : p.split(inputstring))
    System.out.println(s);
```

Either produces:

```
[Computers]-[Apple]-[Laptop]
[Cables]-[Cables,Connectors]
[Adapters]
```

Comment: i have a pattern, but it will split the [6,7,8] into three parts, it is ""[^""\r\n]*""|'[^'\r\n]*'|[^,\r\n]*

Comment: My pattern specifically preserves [6,7,8]

Comment: could you be able to elaborate your pattern please. i tried your pattern, but it does not work

Comment: Perhaps it should be `-(?=\[)`? That is, a hyphen that is followed by a bracket?

Comment: Sorry, i should mention i have to use the Pattern, not Split.  there should be a Pattern, but cannot figure it out yet. anyway thanks for your code example :)

Comment: If you don't know how to translate this into whatever language you're working in, kindly let me know what language that is.

Comment: @Vulcan apologies, misunderstood the question.

Comment: @user1853479 May I suggest you pick up a user name? It's kinda confusing when two anonymous users meet.

Comment: if it will please you jan = )

Answer (score 0):

An answer that doesn't use regular expressions (if that's worth something in ease of understanding what's going on) is:

1. substitute "]@[" for "],["
2. split on "@"

Comment: And if the string has any `@` symbols to begin with, you're out of luck.  The other answer offers a far better solution that doesn't encounter this issue.